# Do any languages have syntax for promises?

Tags: javascript, programming-languages, syntax, language-features, asynchronous-programming

I'm really glad that EcmaScript 6 has promises built into the language, but the syntax will still be quite wordy:

```
new Promise(f).then(r => {
...
}).then(r2 => 
...
}).catch(...
```

I'm just wondering if there are any languages that have syntactic sugar for promises, so the result looks more like conventional imperative programming. Maybe hypothetically something like:

```
fetch f {
get r
  ...
get r2
  ...
catch
  ...
}
```

Comment: I think C#'s async/await does something like this, but I haven't actually used it.

Comment: `async` `await` combined with `Task<T>`.

Comment: Choosing our programming language according to promise syntax, are we?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there are several such languages:

- C# has `async` methods and the `await` keyword. Technically speaking, any object which implements a certain syntactic pattern can be `await`ed, but the *intention* is for this syntax to be used for, well, asynchronous programming, and the only objects in the framework which implement the syntactic pattern are `Task<T>` objects, which are futures/promises (depending on your exact definition of "future" and "promise", they may be futures, promises, both, or neither).
- Visual Basic.NET has the same syntax with the same semantics
- F# has asynchronous workflows, which were the inspiration for `async`/`await`
- In languages with macros, libraries can implement their own syntax (within limits), and so there are promise libraries in Scala, Scheme, Common Lisp, Clojure, and other Lisps, which have what looks like builtin syntax.
- Python 3.5+ has `async` / `await`
- The next version of ECMAScript will very likely have `async`/`await`
- The next version of C++ may or may not have `resumable`/`await`
- And last but very important: Oz does *not* have special syntax for promises, because in Oz *every* variable is a dataflow-variable, and *every* value is a promise!

Comment: Wow - thanks for such a complete list. Hadn't heard of async/await. Here's the ES7 spec for it: http://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/#intro, and  some [sample code](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait/blob/master/server.asyncawait.js)

Comment: Just thought of a missing item for this list: as Promises are essentially a monad, Haskell's "do" notation could be considered just such a syntax. Or indeed any other language with a suitable monad building syntax.